# Interest rate program

Tags: c

I am just beginning to learn C. So for practice I decided to write a interest rate calculator but for some reason my calculation always comes out as 0 and I can't figure it out. If you can please take a look.

```
#include <stdio.h>


main()
{


int time;
float principle, rate, total;

printf("What is your starting amount? ");
scanf(" %f", &principle);
printf("What is your interest rate? ");
scanf(" %f", &rate);
printf("How long do you want to save? ");
scanf(" %d", &time);

total = principle * rate * time;
printf("You will have earned an interest amount of $%d", total);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%d` expects an `int`, not  a `float`.

Comment: Oh Duh, Thank you I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/fMnqhN)

Comment: Also please stop listening to whoever showed you `main()`; that person is not a good influence. It should say `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("You will have earned an interest amount of $%d", total);
```

Since `total` is a float, `%d` should be `%f`. Also, it's a nice touch to throw in a new line at the end of each line.

```
printf("You will have earned an interest amount of $%f\n", total);
```